# use std::move twice when an argument is passed by value?

Tags: c++

I need some feedback in order to see if I understand C++ move semantics correctly. Can someone tell me if the following example of using `std::move` - **including the statements made in the comments** - is correct? (No elaborate comments required if the answer is simply Yes)

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class MyClass
{
public:
  void Set(std::string str)
  {
     myString = std::move(str); 
  }
private:
  std::string myString;
};

int main()
{
  std::string largeString = "A very long piece of text...";
  
  // In the follwoing case largeString is copied once, because it is passed by value (correct?)
  MyClass myClass;
  myClass.Set(largeString);
  
  // In the following case no copies of largeString are made, because it is moved twice (correct?)
  MyClass myClass2;
  myClass.Set(std::move(largeString)); // largeString can no longer be used in main() after this line
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both your `std::move` usages are correct.

Comment: *"largeString can no longer be used in main() after this line"* - it can be used without any problems, however it becomes an empty string.

Comment: "largeString can no longer be used in main() after this line" - as noted above it **can** be used, but after moving from it the string will be empty. It can still be used though (assigned with a new value etc.).

Comment: It won't be "empty". It will be in a valid *but unspecified* state. Don't assume an implementation. It's valid, so you may reassign it reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood it correctly.
Also you can make your own class, log all constructors and check it by yourself.